# How to invalidate Glide cache for some specific images

Tags: android, image, caching, android-glide

I'm writing an app which needs to load a lot of images from the internet (a manga reader). I need to cache some thumbnail images for offline use, any others should be cleared when app closed.

I read some about cache invalidation on Glide page, they said the best way is to change the content url, but how Glide know if it is a modified url of old content or a new one? I'm new to Glide here.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation

Thank in advance :)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to load image:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .signature(new StringSignature(yourVersionMetadata))
    .into(imageView)
```

Just change `yourVersionMetadata` when you load image and it will not load from cache if `yourVersionMetadata` is different.

Comment: Thank, i will try it :) . And i would like to know if the cache will be deleted?

Comment: It seemed that the old version cache was not deleted. When I change the _versionMetadata_ to the old one, the image showed up immediately. So I guess it was not deleted.

Comment: If that is the case then this method may not work for me :) . I want the old cache to be deleted to free up storage.