# Passing Cache Image from one Activity to another Activity

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I load an image from url into an imageview in Activity 1 (using glide). When I switch to activity 2 ,I disconnect my network connection and I'm required to load the same image in another imageview. How am I supposed to achieve this? Can this be done by using the image cached somewhere by glide?

Comment: this solution would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406489/glide-how-to-find-if-the-image-is-already-cached-and-use-the-cached-version

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity1

Convert ImageView to Bitmap

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp = imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("img", bmp);
```

In Activity2

```
  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("img");
  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of caching image using glide create your own cache folder and cache images into it.It can be easily accessible throughout the application

```
  Glide.with(yourImageView.getContext())
                .load("your url")
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                .error(R.drawable.place_holder)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                 //Create a folder for caching and add images from here

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this and this works for me:

Add a OnClickListener like below:

```
    Glide.with(this)
         .load("URL HERE")
         .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
         .into(Image);

    Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent= new Intent(context,FullScreenImage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("image_url", "URL HERE" );
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Then in the new Activity:

```
    public class FullScreenImage extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView myImage;
    String url = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen_image);

        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");

        myImage = findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        Glide.with(this).load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_send_24dp)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_image_send_24dp)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(myImage);
    }
}
```

PS: Dont forget to use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` in both the activities while using glide.