# How to priorly get future Glide image size which will be stored in cache in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

In MainActivity, I'm loading some images using glide into recyclerview according to imageview size.

See:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreviewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context).load(previewArrayList.get(position).getUrl()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC).into(holder.postImage);
}
```

XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/post_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/post_name"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

As you can observe, I'm using Glide cache  `DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC` also so that next time without Internet Glide can show the images. Now you can read in this post https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d that " **`Glide resizes the image as per the dimension of the ImageView.`**"

Now, I want that final size inside SpalshActivity, which Glide will be stored in cache. So that when After SpalshActivity, when user opens MainActivity **without Internet Conncetion** for the very first time also, then it should load Images.

So how is it possible?

In SpalshActivity, I'm already caching Images, but it is again downloading/resizing in MainActivity for the very first time.

SpalshActivity:

```
private void preloadImage(String url) {
        try {

            //File file = Glide.with(this).asFile().load(url).submit().get();
            //String path = file.getPath();


            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(url)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            if (isPostDataLoaded) {
                                postImagesLoaded++;
                                if (postImagesLoaded == postImagesCount) {
                                    binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialogMessage(SplashActivity.this, "Error", "Something went wrong, Please try again later", false, "Exit", null, SplashActivity.this, IS_TABLET);
                                }
                            } else {
                                previewImagesLoaded++;
                                if (previewImagesLoaded == previewImagesCount) {
                                    binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialogMessage(SplashActivity.this, "Error", "Something went wrong, Please try again later", false, "Exit", null, SplashActivity.this, IS_TABLET);
                                }
                            }
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            if (isPostDataLoaded) {
                                postImagesLoaded++;
                                if (postImagesLoaded == postImagesCount) {
                                    PostSingleton.getInstance().setPostMap(postMap);
                                    startFreshActivity(PreviewActivity.class);
                                }
                            } else {
                                previewImagesLoaded++;
                                if (previewImagesLoaded == previewImagesCount) {
                                    PreviewSingleton.getInstance().setPreviewList(previewList);
                                    getPostImageCount();
                                    postPreloadAllImages();
                                }
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }).preload();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to preload all the images with `.downloadOnly()` instead of using any `target`. Then load images using `FileProvider`.

```
private class CacheImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,File> {
        @Override
        protected File doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                return Glide.with(getContext())
                        .load(strings[0])
                        .downloadOnly(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL,Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                        .get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
            if(file!=null){
               Uri file_uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                        getContext().getPackageName()+".images",file);
            }
        }
    }
```

And store the path alongside URL in SQLite.
Now get the `image_url` using `FileProvider` from SQLite

```
Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(<image_url>)
                .asBitmap()
                .dontAnimate()
                .centerCrop()
                .override(<width>,<height>)
                .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(imageView);
```

You may also need to add,

In manifest, inside `<application>`

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="{app package name}.images"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Inside `res/xml`, as `file_paths.xml`,

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <cache-path name="images" path="image_manager_disk_cache"
        tools:path="DiskCache.Factory.DEFAULT_DISK_CACHE_DIR" />
</paths>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll implement this. Please give some time

Comment: Use SQLite to store the value you get from CacheImage along with the base image URL

In DB table, CacheImageTable(url TEXT UNIQUE, file_path TEXT)

Comment: Sure. I'll do that