# Manifest: missing required attribute: autoRevokePermissions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

application tag and application inside manifest is showing red color. When I moved cursor it is suggesting: missing required attribute: autoRevokePermissions

Two options are there:
android:autoRevokePermissions="allowed"
android:autoRevokePermissions="discouraged"

What should I chose and why?

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:autoRevokePermissions="allowed">
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jimmytrivedi.android.iwishwithprachi"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

I read here, but I'm not getting:
https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/permissions#request-disable-auto-reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have set your `targetSdkVersion` to 30, Android 11 is now capable to automatically revoke `(i.e android system will automatically deny the granted permissions when the app is not used for a few months)` user permissions. That's the reason `android:autoRevokePermissions` is a required attribute. If you don't want to specify the attribute you can lower down your `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 29 (though not recommended)

`android:autoRevokePermissions` has 3 values: `allowed`, `disallowed`, `discouraged`

Read here,
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#autoRevokePermissions

Comment: Tell me the diff between 3 values: allowed, disallowed, discouraged

Comment: Thnak you so much Raj

Comment: Can you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624070/how-to-priorly-get-future-glide-image-size-which-will-be-stored-in-cache-in-andr

Comment: @PriyankaSingh allowed => Android system may revoke the permissions automatically if the app is unused for few months

disallowed => Android system will not revoke the permissions automatically even if the app is unused for a few months

discouraged => App can request the user whether or not to revoke the permission. (by starting an activity with Intent.ACTION_AUTO_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS.

Comment: Okay, but pease help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624070/how-to-priorly-get-future-glide-image-size-which-will-be-stored-in-cache-in-andr